# Black after exporting asset previews as images

Tags: python, scripting, image, asset-browser, asset

I want to export asset previews as images. I borrowed some codes from [Blender 3.0: Is there a way to quickly create thumbnails for material and object assets?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/249319/blender-3-0-is-there-a-way-to-quickly-create-thumbnails-for-material-and-object) and [this github page](https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities/blob/520c917fdc3470685001ee6cbc1ed1f975428056/module/preview/operator/extract.py#L22-L37:%7E:text=asset_preview%20%3D%20asset,.save()). I first created previews for assets, then created images of the previews, and finally saved the images, like below:

```
import bpy
from asset_browser_utilities.module.preview.tool import create_image

assets = [o for o in bpy.data.objects if o.asset_data]
>>> assets
[bpy.data.objects['IfcBeam/SBS-STR-AEC-Concrete:H900W950:4099546'], bpy.data.objects['IfcColumn/COL-STR-AEC-Concrete:W1200H1400:4099287']]

beam = assets[0]
beam.asset_generate_preview()
preview = beam.preview
>>> preview
bpy.data.objects['IfcBeam/SBS-STR-AEC-Concrete:H900W950:4099546']...ImagePreview

img = create_image(beam.name, preview.image_size[0], preview.image_size[1])
img.file_format = "PNG"
img.filepath = "//beam.png"
img.save()
```

The asset previews are shown like below:

[image]

But the saved image is all black, like below:

[image]

The file is [here](https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities/blob/520c917fdc3470685001ee6cbc1ed1f975428056/module/preview/operator/extract.py#L22-L37:%7E:text=asset_preview%20%3D%20asset,.save()). I think the asset previews show that the previews have been created successfully. Then why the exported images would become black? How to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this great tool](https://github.com/Gorgious56/asset_browser_utilities) to meet my need of exporting previews as images in batch! But I am still wondering about the reasons about this black bug using the codes by myself...

Comment: Hello ! I'm the author of this addon. :) The reason is that the preview generation is asynchronous (to not block the interface while generating) and takes a bit of time to complete, so if you try to save the image right in the next line of code, the data doesn't have enough time to be generated. You can add a bit of time buffer with [application timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html) usually 1 second is enough ,but it can take more if it's a material or a complex mesh

Comment: @Gorgious I see! Thank you very much for your explanation, and the awesome addon! :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).