# When marking assets by python api, the thumbnail does not show properly in the asset browser can not see the image

Tags: python

When marking assets by python api, the icon does not show properly in the asset browser can not see the thumbnail. But I can mark the asset.

```
       obj = bpy.data.objects["dishwasher1"]  
       obj.asset_clear()
       obj.asset_mark()
```

Any one can help on this?

Comment: Not a duplicate per se but I suggest you also read through this thread https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274982/86891

Answer (score 4):

Let's have a look at what Python Console suggests with autocomplete:

[image]

`object.asset_generate_preview()` looks interesting.

Comment: A link to the method docs for completeness : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.asset_generate_preview

Comment: Note the generation is asynchronous so you won't be able to access the image data directly after calling `asset_generate_preview` but you can use [application timers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html) to wait for a bit for the preview to render.

Comment: Absolutely worked out! Fantastic!